# Extract timestamp from a given string using python

Tags: python

I tried multiple packages to extract timestamp from a given string, but no package gives correct results. I did use `dateutils`, `datefinder`, `parsedatetime`, etc. for this task. They extract some datetimes which are in certain formats but not all formats, sometimes they extract some unwanted numbers also as timestamps.

Is there any python package which extracts `datetime` from a given string.

Assume, I have 2 strings like these:

```
scala> val xorder= new order(1,"2016-02-22 00:00:00.00",100,"COMPLETED")
```

and

```
Fri, 10 Jun 2011 11:04:17 +0200 (CEST)
```

and want to extract only `datetime`. Is there any function which extracts both formats of `datetimes` from above strings. In other cases formats may be different, still it should pick out `datetime` strings

Comment: Could you give us an example of input string you want to extract a timestamp from?

Comment: Assume, I have 2 strings like these. 'scala> val xorder= new order(1,"2016-02-22 00:00:00.00",100,"COMPLETED")' and 'Fri, 10 Jun 2011 11:04:17 +0200 (CEST)' and want to extract only datetime. Is there any function which extracts both formats of datetimes from above strings. In other cases formats may be different, still it should pick out datetime strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the datetime function strptime() as follows

```
dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

You can create your own formatting and use the function as well.

Comment: The above function you mentioned can be useful once datetime strings are extracted from text summaries. We need to pull out those strings first. Ex:- 'scala> val xorder= new order(1,"2016-02-22 00:00:00.00",100,"COMPLETED")' from this first, we need to extract "2016-02-22 00:00:00" and then convert it to python datetime.

Answer (score -1):

I created a small python package **datetime_extractor** to pull out timestamps from a given strings. It can extract many datetime formats from given strings. Hope it will be useful.

```py
pip install datetime-extractor

from datetime_extractor import DateTimeExtractor
import re

samplestring1 = 'scala> val xorder= new order(1,"2016-02-22 00:00:00.00",100,"COMPLETED")'

DateTimeExtractor(samplestring1)

Out: ['2016-02-22 00:00:00.00']

samplestring2 = 'Fri, 10 Jun 2011 11:04:17 +0200 (CEST)'

DateTimeExtractor(samplestring2)

Out: ['10 Jun 2011 11:04:17']
```

@Allan & @Manmeet Singh, Let me know your comments.